# Can't install anything on Lubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder, systemd, dbus

I am running the latest version of Lubuntu and it gives me the same error every time I try to install something ::

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-cffi-backend
 python3-keyring
 python3-crypto
 python3-idna
 python3-xdg
 python3-keyrings.alt
 python3-six
 python3-dev
 python3-wheel
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-gi
 python3-asn1crypto
 python3-pip
 python3-setuptools
 python3-lib2to3
 python3-secretstorage
 dh-python
 python3-distutils
 python3-cryptography
 python3-dbus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me I have a python test tomorrow at my college and this is really giving me a hard time, I need to practice codes.

EDIT:: I don't know why but only python here is giving me a problem

UPDATE:: Now it gives me a different error :

Here I was trying to install Spyder3 using:`sudo apt-get install spyder3`

```
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: while you figure it out you can look at websites that let you run python code, eg.-  https://repl.it/ to practice

Comment: Thanks @VaibhaVishal that will help me work. After tomorrow I have ample amount of time to research and solve this but a permanent solution from experts would be very helpful.

Comment: Your question isn't really on-topic here, and doesn't contain enough information anyway to know what happened when you tried to install 'something'. When asking questions, always show us exactly what you did and what errors or unexpected vs expected output you got.

Comment: Here I was trying to install a screenshot app by `sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot` but it gave me this error. What's funny is that the app got installed and it functions properly but while installing I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `/etc/resolv.conf`

Backup the file before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sudo apt-get install spyder3` with `sudo pip install spyder3`

If you hade other error please show me and also show me command in terminal